# Как скопировать файл от имени администратора?

Tags: winapi, windows, c++, visual-c++

Приветствую!
Возникла проблема.
Нужно скопировать некоторый файл, этот файл иногда доступен только администратору.

Вопрос такой, возможно ли как-нибудь выполнить функцию CopyFile c правами администратора или на время выполнения этой функции присвоить права администратора.

**UPD**

Ещё есть некоторое уточнение, юзер является членом группs Backup Operators. Насколько я помню эта группа имеет привилегии на смену владельца.

```
BOOL TakeOwnership(LPTSTR lpszOwnFile)
{
    BOOL bRetval = FALSE;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL; 
    PSID pSIDBackup = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDBackup = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    DWORD dwRes;
  if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDBackup, 1,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_BACKUP_OPS,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pSIDBackup)) 
  {
    printf("AllocateAndInitializeSid (Backup) error %u\n",
        GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
  }
  if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), 
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, 
    &hToken)) 
  {
    printf("OpenProcessToken failed: %u\n", GetLastError()); 
    goto Cleanup; 
  } 
  if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, TRUE)) 
  {
    printf("You must be logged on as Administrator.\n");
    goto Cleanup; 
  }
  dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(
    lpszOwnFile,
    SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
    OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
    pSIDBackup, 
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL); 
  if (dwRes != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
  {
    printf("Could not set owner. Error: %u\n", dwRes); 
    goto Cleanup;
  }
  if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, FALSE)) 
  {
    printf("Failed SetPrivilege call unexpectedly.\n");
    goto Cleanup;
  }

   Cleanup:
    if (pSIDBackup)
        FreeSid(pSIDBackup); 
    if (hToken)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    return bRetval;
```

}

Вываливается с ошибкой `ERROR_INVALID_OWNER` 1307 (0x51B)
Я так понял что-то с SID намутил

Comment: свойства -> безопасность -> ставишь юзеру нужные права...

Comment: Как это можно выполнить программно на c++?
Логин и пароль администратора известны.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat Жалко, что нельзя минусовать комменты `:)`

Answer (score 8):

*Общее решение* для всех возможных сценариев выглядит следующим образом:

- Взять текущий токен пользователя с помощью вызова [`OpenThreadToken(NULL, TOKEN_QUERY, ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379296).
- Явно проверить для полученного токена наличие требуемых прав путем вызова [`AccessCheck(...),`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa374815) либо сделать опосредованный вывод на основании информации об этом токене, которую можно получить путем вызова [`GetTokenInformation(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa446671).

> - Скажем, для `Elevated` (`TOKEN_ELEVATION`) токена может быть автоматически известно, что все требуемые права есть, и ни о чем больше беспокоиться не надо.

- В случае, если текущих прав недостаточно, их нужно запросить. Здесь варианты следующие:

> - Если прав у пользователя достаточно в принципе, но недостаточно из-за `UAC` (советую разобраться с тем, как в `UAC'e` происходит фильтрация токенов), то нужно вызвать `UAC Prompt` для вашей операции.
> - Самый простой способ это сделать — запустить отдельный исполняемый файл, у которого в манифесте будет указан параметр [`requireAdministrator,`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384691) или же просто использовать аналогичный манифест для вашего **исходного приложения.**
> - Если у пользователя нехватает прав в принципе, то нужно запускать отдельный процесс (тот же самый или некоторый `hosted process`) от `credential'ов` другого пользователя. Сделать это можно, вызвав функцию [`LogonUser(...) /`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa378184) [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa375178) и запустив процесс с новым токеном путем вызова [`CreateProcessAsUser(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682429).
> - Здесь кажется разумным расшарить логику определения текущих прав, поскольку, возможно, ее нужно повторять в цикле (то есть, пока не дадут правильные `credentials` для совершения желаемой операции или не отменят эту самую операцию).
> - Учтите также, что на `Windows XP,` где понятия `"Elevation"` нет в принципе, некоторых из описанных функций **просто нет,** но на `Windows XP` сама проблема решается несколько проще и очевиднее.

- Если известна какая-то дополнительная информация про токен текущего пользователя, то некоторые шаги из описанного подхода можно *выкинуть* или *упростить.*